# Didn't found any documentation for tkEntrySeeInsert

Tags: tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I found at many places in TK programming `tkEntrySeeInsert %W`.

But din't find any proper documentation.
What actually **tkEntrySeeInsert** does?

Answer (score 0):

It scrolls the contents of the entry widget so that the insertion cursor is visible.

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented because it is part of the implementation of Tk, not the interface of Tk. It changed name in Tk 8.5 to `::tk::EntrySeeInsert` — not an announced change *per se* — precisely because it was internal to how Tk works.

It's implementation and internal documentation comment (from Tk 8.6) are this:

```
# ::tk::EntrySeeInsert --
# Make sure that the insertion cursor is visible in the entry window.
# If not, adjust the view so that it is.
#
# Arguments:
# w -           The entry window.

proc ::tk::EntrySeeInsert w {
    set c [$w index insert]
    if {($c < [$w index @0]) || ($c > [$w index @[winfo width $w]])} {
        $w xview $c
    }
}
```

It probably helps if you know what `@`***x***-style indices do: they convert from (horizontal) widget-level screen coordinates to character indices.